# Screenshot Issue on iPad in Landscape mode

Tags: xcode, ipad, screenshot, landscape

I have the attached code in my application that takes a screenshot of the view before emailing it. It works fine for Portrait mode but cuts off a section in Landscape mode. Running on IOS7.
Can anyone help me please ?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotimage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: I kind of doubt it will make a difference here, but the `CGGeometry.h` reference says not to directly access the members of `CGRect` structs, and instead to use `CGRectGetWidth()` and `CGRectGetHeight()`. It’s good practice, and it would be worth a try here.

Comment: That is, your first line should read: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));` (You can split it into multiple lines or make the size a variable if you want to make it cleaner.)

Comment: Hmmm Still getting my landscape screenshots with the last 1/3 cut off when it creates an image file ?